# Does a set with the following properties hold?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Does there exist an infinite subset, $S$, of the real numbers such that both of the following are true:

1. $\forall a,b\in S, \exists c\in S$ such that $a+b=c$
2. $\forall c \in S, \exists a,b \in S$ such that $ab\neq c$

My suspicion is that such a set does not exist, but I'm not entirely sure. I know that the real numbers are closed under both addition and multiplication, but I'm not sure if this will help.

Comment: $\{n\pi\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ satisfies those conditions. (1) because $n\pi+m\pi=(n+m)\pi$. (2) because if $m\pi=r\pi s\pi$, then $\pi$ satisfies a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: With $\exists$ you can just take $\mathbf R$ in its entirety. For all $c \in \mathbf R$ take $a = c + 1$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: No, I did mean $\exists$ for 2.

Comment: Every infinite subset satisfies (2): if $c=0$ choose $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$; if $c\ne0$ choose $a=c$, $b\ne1$.